# How can I fix ? Remote - WSL will not open on VSCode - Error says `Multi distro not supported'

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded Ubuntu and then downloaded Remote - wsl on VSCode. I followed Ubuntu's prompts to access Remote - wsl extension by typing `code .` When I type `code .` VSCode opens but then quickly disconnects. It gives me an error - "Multi distro support requires a newer version of wsl" (windows 10, May 2019 update, version 1903) but I only have one distro (Ubuntu), and Windows 10 is updated. Image of error here:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

I followed this tutorial from `Microsoft`
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/an-in-depth-tutorial-on-linux-development-on-windows-with-wsl-and-visual-studio-code/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add more details to your question? It will make easier for people to try to help you with it.

Comment: It's updated thanks

Comment: Try some random tests -- Delete the VSCode extension folder or Reinstall the extension or delete the vscode server folder in WSL user home directory or check if you really have latest Windows 10 release or install VSCode insider in Windows.

Comment: Those are really good ideas, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Windows 11 using WSL2 and Ubuntu 2022.04.1LTS
WSL disconnected issue:
[image: WSL disconnected issue]

I was able to fix it by disabling the WSL extension and then reenabling it.

Disable and reenable the WSL extension:
[image: Disable and reenable the WSL extension]
Both will require a reload VSCode.

Answer (score -2):

## Perform these steps

(1) delete .vscode

## Disallow .VSCODE In GitIgnore

(2) add this:  .vscode

Comment: Then restart the terminal or cmd tool